# Using string.ToUpper on substring

Tags: c#, string

Have an assignment to allow a user to input a word in C# and then display that word with the first and third characters changed to uppercase. Code follows:

```
namespace Capitalizer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ' };
            string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
            string Upper = text.ToUpper();
            Console.WriteLine(Upper);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This of course generates the entire word in uppercase, which is not what I want. I can't seem to make text.ToUpper(0,2) work, and even then that'd capitalize the first three letters. Only solution I can think of now that would make the word appear on one line (and I don't know if it works) is to move the capitalized letters and lowercase letters into a character array and try to get that to print all values in a modified order.

Comment: where are you using substring..? [MSDN SubString Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This is a more complicated question than you know. Unicode is a variable-length encoding, so the first and third visible "character" might not be text[0] and text[2].

Comment: _"with the first and third characters changed to uppercase"_ -- did you write that correctly? If so, why are you splitting the string? What does `words` have to do with this question at all? Conversely, if `words` is relevant, a) why don't you use it in the code, and b) please explain _in your question_ how it's relevant and what the actual requirements here are.

Comment: "words" was me trying to get the string into an array, I copy-pasted it from a similar assignment. The assignment verbatim is as follows:

"Write a program that prompts the user to enter a word in all lowercase. Convert the first and third letters to uppercase and output the string."

Comment: _""words" was me trying to get the string into an array"_ -- well, okay. But why were you trying to do that? The problem statement doesn't seem to require that, or involve arrays of any sort. Also, note that while you receive notifications of any comments on your question, commenters generally won't know you've responded unless you type the `@` symbol followed by their user name. E.g. @AB.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've been typing that, but it hasn't been registering (did now, though)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way I can think of to address your exact question as described — to convert to upper case the first and third *characters* of the input — would be something like the following:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);

sb[0] = char.ToUpper(sb[0]);
sb[2] = char.ToUpper(sb[2]);

text = sb.ToString();
```

The `StringBuilder` class is essentially a mutable string object, so when doing these kinds of operations is the most fluid way to approach the problem, as it provides the most straightforward conversions to and from, as well as the full range of string operations. Changing individual characters is easy in many data structures, but insertions, deletions, appending, formatting, etc. all also come with `StringBuilder`, so it's a good habit to use that versus other approaches.

But frankly, it's hard to see how that's a useful operation. I can't help but wonder if you have stated the requirements incorrectly and there's something more to this question than is seen here.

Comment: Thank you.  The assignment looks busyworkish, but here it is:

"Write a program that prompts the user to enter a word in all lowercase. Convert the first and third letters to uppercase and output the string."

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ:

```
var upperCaseIndices = new[] { 0, 2 };
var message = "hello";
var newMessage = new string(message.Select((c, i) =>
  upperCaseIndices.Contains(i) ? Char.ToUpper(c) : c).ToArray());
```

Here is how it works. `message.Select` (inline [LINQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19154/Understanding-LINQ-C) query) selects characters from `message` one by one and passes into selector function:

```
upperCaseIndices.Contains(i) ? Char.ToUpper(c) : c
```

written as [C# ?: shorthand syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) for `if`. It reads as "If index is present in the array, then select upper case character. Otherwise select character as is."

```
(c, i) => condition
```

is a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). See also:

- [Understand Lambda Expressions in 3 minutes](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-minutes)

The rest is very simple - represent result as array of characters (`.ToArray()`), and create a new string based off that (`new string(...)`).

Comment: I do not think that the OP will understand this awesome answer since Substrings function is a lot easier to understand than lambda and ?: Operator great answer by the way.. +1

Comment: @MethodMan: Thanks. I added some explanation with links. Hope it's easier to digest now. :)

Comment: @CoryNelson: I understand that most efficient solution would be a simple for loop + string builder + an if to check for index being 0 or 2. However, I don't think efficiency is in scope for OP right now. In any case, feel free to add your answer below.

Comment: @Neolisk, Underscored answer, nice!

Answer (score 2):

> Only solution I can think of now that would make the word appear on one line (and I don't know if it works) is to move the capitalized letters and lowercase letters into a character array and try to get that to print all values in a modified order.

That seems a lot more complicated than necessary. Once you have a character array, you can simply change the elements of that character array. In a separate function, it would look something like

```
string MakeFirstAndThirdCharacterUppercase(string word) {
  var chars = word.ToCharArray();
  chars[0] = chars[0].ToUpper();
  chars[2] = chars[2].ToUpper();
  return new string(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution:

```
string text = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] delimiterChars = { ' ' };
        string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);

        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();

            chars[0] = char.ToUpper(chars[0]);
            if (chars.Length > 2)
            {
                chars[2] = char.ToUpper(chars[2]);
            }
            Console.Write(new string(chars));
            Console.Write(' ');
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that ToUpper doesn't work on charArrays

Comment: Weird. I continuously got "no overload for method ToUpper takes 0 arguments.

Either way, assignment successfully completed.

Comment: Did you copy and paste my code above directly into your Main method? And congratulations for the assignment